# Get the name of the current iPhone xib being viewed

Tags: iphone, ipad, compare, nib, xib

I have 3 xib files connected to the same class to reduce duplicate coding. However, there are different stuff that I want done when the new nib file loads (i.e. in the ViewDidLoad method). I've thought about doing an if statement to compare the name of the xib currently being displayed to a string. I have been trying to figure out how to do that for most of the day but I haven't had any luck. Here's some pseudo code if that confused you:

```
if (currentXibInDisplay == @"XibFileName1")
   // Do This...
else if (currentXibInDisplay == @"XibFileName2")
   // Do This...
```

There is a way to do that, right? It seems pretty simple but I am pretty stumped right now. Thanks for any info you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the nibname

if you say: `NSString *name = self.view.nibname` you can proove it with

```
`[name isEqual:@"XIBName"]`
```

Comment: Are the views in one single view or are sperated?

Comment: Because if these subviews are in a singleview,.. you can say 'self.view.viewControllers <<-- NSArray'

Comment: Thanks alot fuzi. I tried your code using self.view.nibname but it didn't find nibname under view. I tried it using self.nibname and it worked. That's exactly what I needed. Thanks everybody for your input.

Comment: But self.nibname always shows the name of nib, used in initWithNib: method. If you reload controller view from bundle by [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:owner:options:] self.nibName stay the same as originals.

Answer (score 5):

I tried to use it with

```
self.view.nibName;
```

But it won't work, instead try this

```
self.nibName;
```

Answer (score 0):

The view controller that you're loading has the `initWithNibNamed:` method, you can override there and store which XIB is going to be loaded.

Comment: The problem for this approach is that the nib name paramater can be nil.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you correctly. I'm not having a problem with actually loading the new XIB into the view. The thing is that if one particular view is loaded, I want some extra stuff done in the ViewDidLoad method. But I don't know how to detect if that xib is loaded. If I miss understood you, I apologize. This is my first real project for iOS. If you could point me to an example or something I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I tried doing something along the lines of if([self.nibName compare:@"CompareisonString"])... but that didn't help. That is always "true" no matter what is in the compare string.

Comment: The reason compare: didn't work is that returns 0 if they are the same. And yes, using nibname is the correct solution, my bad

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I almost figured it out on my own. I was just using the wrong method call. Oh, well. Atleast I'm learning something.

Answer (score 0):

ViewController subclasses have a nibName string property you can check against:

```
[self.nibName isEqualTo:@"XIBFileName"]
```